# schtasks.exe: Task Scheduler can't create a task from XML

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to build a command that I can use in my Inno Setup installer to update my program on a schedule. This is what I have so far.

```
schtasks /CREATE /TN "Search Deflector Updater" /RU SYSTEM /SC DAILY /TR "[REDACTED]\update.exe" /XML "updatetask.xml" /F
```

The `/RU SYSTEM` is for hiding the console window that is created by my update executable.

The `/TR "[REDACTED]\updater.exe"` is an absolute normalized path to the updater executable in the program's install location.

And most importantly, `/XML "updatetasks.xml"` is the file with the settings the task should be created with. If I use this, I need one of `/S`, `/U`, `/P`, `/RU`, `/RP`, `/F`, `/IT`, or `/TN`.

I have specified `/TN`, `/F`, and `/RU` but I still get an error when running the command.

```
ERROR: /XML option can only be used with /S /U /P /RU /RP /F /IT /TN
```

I don't understand why, I've met all of the requirements.

My XML is below. Additionally, suggestions on minimizing the markup to only the absolute necessary settings to make the task function as expected would be appreciated. Things that have defaults that the XML doesn't need to explicitly specify/change, or settings that aren't used/redundant, should be omitted. I just don't know what they are.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
<Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
    </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
</Triggers>
<Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
    <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
</Principals>
<Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>true</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
    <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
    <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
    <Interval>PT5M</Interval>
    <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
</Settings>
</Task>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why no path on the XML, just generally bad programming practise? Help (`schtasks /create /?`) says *Can be combined with /RU and /RP switches, or with /RP alone, when task XML already contains the principal.*

Comment: No path on the XML file because I'm just testing the command out. There will be an absolute path when I add it to the installer script.